# Change hotkey category in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I change a hotkey category in Eclipse? E.g. I need to set a key for the "Next bookmark", but this command is under "C/C++ source" category, and my hotkey doesn't work in Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this link:

[How to Manage Keyboard Shortcuts in Eclipse and Why You Should](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/how-manage-keyboard-shortcuts)

And you can go "Window\Preferences\General\Keys" and can Unbind or Bind hotkeys to commands at WHEN (means category e.g. Debug, In Window, Java ,...) it work.

And for custom binding you can follow this link:

[Define key bindings for Eclipse Commands - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCommandsKeybindings/article.html)

Comment: This doesn't work. I've tried "In Windows", "Editing Java source", "Editing text" for WHEN field. I'm afraid "C/C++ source" category for this command matters.

Comment: I mean, apart from WHEN there's a CATEGORY field, and it's set to "C/C++ source" which I can't change.

Comment: This is the best useful link:
[Define key bindings for Eclipse Commands - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCommandsKeybindings/article.html)

and I'll edit in answer.

Comment: Ahmad, thanks for the reference. I guess that's what should help me. But it'll take time to learn how to make everything work since I'm new to plugin development.